# Using imported (required) routes file is not recognized when doing http requests

Tags: node.js, express, router

This is my server file in which in import some routes (userRoutes from instance)

```
const express  = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyPraser = require('body-parser')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth.routes')
const userRoutes = require('./routes/auth.routes')
const app = express()

//Use Middleware and routes 
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyPraser.json())
app.use(cookieParser())


//require routes


authRoutes(app)
userRoutes(app)

....
```

When i send a get request in post man to localhost:3003/x i get a 404 error.
What am i missing here exactly?

Comment: Please share the userRoutes file please

Comment: ```
module.exports = app =>{
app.get('/x',(req,res)=>{
    res.json('it works')
})
//Get all users
app.get('/api/users', async (req,res)=>{
    let users = await userRoute.query()
    res.status(200).json(users) 
})

//Get user by id
app.get('/api/users/:id', async (req,res)=>{
    let { id } = req.params
    let user = await userRoute.getById(id)
    res.status(200).json(user) 
})

//Get user with images


module.exports = userRoutes```

Comment: had a very stupid typo! its fixed